# Input shapes of Conv1D and MaxPooling1D

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, tensorflow, keras

I am new to tensorflow Keras. I am building a CNN to train on my 1D input. I am looking for help regarding the input sizes of the Conv1D and MaxPooling1D layers.

Right now, a feature typically looks something like this:
[1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
Similarly, it uses a one-hot label like this:
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

I have 80 of these pairs.

They are split 50-50 (for training and validation) and the features are reshaped to (1, 2080, 1) since numpy says my array is of size 2080.

```
num_classes = 10
model = keras.Sequential()

model.add(keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=[2080,1]))
model.add(keras.layers.Conv1D(filters = 32, kernel_size=5, strides=1, padding ='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(keras.layers.MaxPooling1D(pool_size = (10), strides=(5),data_format='channels_first'))
model.add(keras.layers.Flatten())
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(512, activation='relu'))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))
#model.summary()
```

My input is fed succesfully through InputLayer and Conv1D,i was expecting the same for the rest of the layers. However, the following error is returned:
expected dense_1 to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape (1, 40, 10)

Comment: Why 2080? Shouldn´t your input be something like (num_samples, num_features)?

Answer (score 1):

The error has possibly to do with your features data and your label data. Make sure that your features data has the following shape (1, 2080, 1) and your label this one: (1, 10).

Here is a working code:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Activation, Conv1D, MaxPooling1D, Flatten
import numpy as np

num_classes = 10
model = Sequential()

model.add(Dense(input_shape=[2080,1], units=10))
model.add(Conv1D(filters = 32, kernel_size=5, strides=1, padding ='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size = (10), strides=(5), data_format='channels_first'))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(512, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adam')

x_train = np.random.random((1, 2080, 1))
y_train = np.random.randint(10, size=(10))
y_train = np.reshape(y_train, (1, 10))
model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=5, batch_size=32)
```

[live code](https://repl.it/@kedevked/keras-simple-model)